# SQL What's wrong with my query

Tags: mysql, sql, lua

```
SELECT 'name'  FROM 'players' WHERE 'id' IN
    (SELECT 'player_id' from 'players_online' WHERE 'frags'=
    (SELECT MAX(frags) FROM 'players_online')) 
AND 'name' is not null LIMIT 1;
```

There are two tables, in second one there are important maximum of column called frags and i want to extract a name from table 1 where columns id and player_id have this same values. When i check it with no single quotes it works but i need to keep a quotes cause of lua script phraser return a bool expression not a string

Lua code:

```
BestPAl=db.storeQuery("SELECT name FROM players WHERE id IN(SELECT player_id from players_online WHERE frags=(SELECT MAX(frags) FROM players_online)) AND name is not null LIMIT 1;")
BestPA=result.getDataString(BestPAl)'code'
```

Comment: ¿The message error?

Comment: #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok ''players' WHERE 'id' IN(SELECT 'player_id' from 'players_online' WHERE 'frags'=(' 

I need to keep this single quotes cause i want to extract a string in a lua script and i get a bool expression not a string when i leave quotes

Comment: Single quoted text in SQL form string literals, not identifiers. Your first query tries to select from the string "players", which is not valid syntax. You must either use no quotes or double quotes. Also, please explain what you mean by "phraser" (do you mean "parser"?)

Comment: Did you mean `BestPA=result.getDataString(BestPAl,"name")`?

Comment: I have resolved this problem by using two queries

**local BestPAl=db.storeQuery("SELECT `player_id` FROM

 `players_online` ORDER BY `frags` DESC LIMIT 1")

local BestPA=result.getDataInt(BestPAl, "player_id")

result.free(BestPAl)

local BestPAm=db.storeQuery("SELECT `name` FROM `players`

 WHERE `id` = " .. BestPA )

local nejm=result.getDataString(BestPAm, "name")

result.free(BestPAm)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes for table and field names. Try it like this

```
SELECT name FROM players WHERE id IN(SELECT player_id from players_online WHERE frags=(SELECT MAX(frags) FROM players_online)) AND name is not null LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yes but i got a bool expression not a string when i using phraser included to lua
**local BestPAl=db.storeQuery("SELECT name FROM players WHERE id IN(SELECT player_id from players_online WHERE frags=(SELECT MAX(frags) FROM players_online)) AND name is not null LIMIT 1;")
BestPA=result.getDataString(BestPAl)**

Comment: I'm not familiar with lua. You can try verifying your query by running it directly against the database using mysql workbench for example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, result of this problem may look like a solution before:

```
local BestPAl=db.storeQuery("SELECT `player_id` FROM `players_online` ORDER BY `frags` DESC LIMIT 1")
local BestPA=result.getDataInt(BestPAl, "player_id")
result.free(BestPAl)
local BestPAm=db.storeQuery("SELECT `name` FROM `players` WHERE `id` = " .. BestPA )
```

I divided query into two, each of them is written to variable. Atention! this code in lua refers to own functions implemented in supported program.